# What is the spacing between interference fringes?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, wavelength

In this problem, we are trying to determine the spacing between interference fringes for a setup of two optically flat glass plates with a small wedge of air between them.

I am attaching a screenshot from a video here (the link is below as well). The person making the video is showing that he derived the equation (distance = number of fringes * wavelength) from knowing that this problem involves constructive interference.

[image: Physics Ninja video screenshot]

My main question is, how does the situation being constructive interference tell you how many fringes there are in a given distance?

Thank you very much.

https://youtu.be/KC-2ZngxNYc

Comment: The inputs are (1) the number of fringes $n$, and (2) the wavelength of the light $\lambda$. The output is the distance $d$. If you write the corresponding relationship you can pf course rearrange the terms. Nevertheless, we will always need to inputs to calculate the missing term.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question was more along the lines of, what is the justification for saying the distance d = 2y? I know it has something to do with the fact that it is constructive interference here but I am a little hazy on the physics of it.

Answer (score 1):

I guy on the video messed things up, The explanation for the relations goes like this:

We know that two waves interfere constructively when the path difference is integer multiple of  wavelength so that
$$\Delta \phi=2m\pi\Rightarrow \Lambda=m\lambda \ \ (\text{constructive interference})$$
Further, If you consider near-normal near normal incident of light then the path difference would be
$$\Lambda=2md\pm \frac{\lambda}{2}$$
An additional $\lambda/2$ path difference due to the fact a ray goes reflected from low refractive index to high got an abrupt change of $\pi $ phase difference. The above formula, You can recall from [thin film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference) with $\cos\theta\approx 1$.

Thus we obtain conditions
$$2nd_m=\left( m+\frac{1}{2}\right)\lambda  \ \ (\text{constructive interference})$$
$$2nd_m=m\lambda \ \ (\text{destructive interference})$$
Note $d_m$ is same as $y$ in your figure. Further for small angle, I can write
$$d_m=x_m\alpha$$
where $x_m$ is the distance of the point  of reflection from one end of the wedge.
$$x_m=\left( m+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\lambda}{2n\alpha}$$
$$\boxed{\Delta x=x_{m+1}-x_m=\frac{\lambda}{2n\alpha}}$$